# SSL: SAN not populated

Tags: openssl, ssl, certificates

I'm trying to create my self-signed certificate:

1. CA private key creation: `openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048`
2. CA certificate creation (see `ca.cnf`'s content bellow): `openssl req -x509 -new -key ca.key -out ca.crt -days 10000 -config ca.cnf`
3. Service private key creation: `openssl genrsa -out cert.key 2048`
4. Create csr (see `node.cnf` bellow): `openssl req -new -key cert.key -out cert.csr -config node.cnf`
5. Create server certificate: `openssl x509 -req -in cert.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out cert.crt -days 100`

After that, I0ve tried to check if my SAN are populated:

I'm getting that:

```
openssl x509 -noout -ext subjectAltName -in cert.crt
No extensions in certificate
```

Any ideas?

`ca.cnf` file is:

```
# OpenSSL CA configuration file
[ ca ]
default_ca = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
default_days = 365
database = index.txt
serial = serial.txt
default_md = sha256
copy_extensions = copy
unique_subject = no

# Used to create the CA certificate.
[ req ]
prompt=no
distinguished_name = distinguished_name
x509_extensions = extensions

[ distinguished_name ]
organizationName = jeusdi
commonName = cicdgitops

[ extensions ]
keyUsage = critical,digitalSignature,nonRepudiation,keyEncipherment,keyCertSign
basicConstraints = critical,CA:true,pathlen:1

# Common policy for nodes and users.
[ signing_policy ]
organizationName = supplied
commonName = optional

# Used to sign node certificates.
[ signing_node_req ]
keyUsage = critical,digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth,clientAuth

# Used to sign client certificates.
[ signing_client_req ]
keyUsage = critical,digitalSignature,keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth
```

`node.cnf`:

```
# OpenSSL node configuration file
[ req ]
prompt=no
distinguished_name = distinguished_name
req_extensions = extensions

[ distinguished_name ]
organizationName = jeusdi

[ extensions ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = registry.localhost
DNS.2 = host.k3d.internal
```

Comment: See crossdupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69273181/self-signed-ssl-certificate-subject-alternative-name-san-gets-lost and more I linked there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The man for [openssl x509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-x509.html) says the following:

> **-extfile filename**
> file containing certificate extensions to use. If not specified then no extensions are added to the certificate.

You can use the `-extfile` option along with `-extensions` to point openssl to the correct extension.  You need to tell it which file to use `-extfile node.cnf` and which section `-extensions extensions` as follows:

```
$ openssl x509 -req -in cert.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out cert.crt -days 100 -extfile node.cnf -extensions extensions
```

After which you get:

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -ext subjectAltName -in cert.crt
X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
    DNS:registry.localhost, DNS:host.k3d.internal
```

Comment: Although 3.0.0 (covered by the page you linked which is for 'head' version) adds `-copy_extensions` for `-req` and `-x509toreq` -- which both say "extensions are not copied **by default**"